# Forcing one then() statement to wait for completion of the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React and getting data from my Firestore DB in my `componentDidMount()` method. I have two `then()` calls, one for when the data from the DB becomes available and I can save it, and the other for adjusting the state.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("myCollection")
        .get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().field1);
                allData.push(doc.data());
            })
        })
        .then(
          console.log("Setting State"),
          this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: allData
        }))
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });

  }
```

However, when I run the site, it attempts to set the state (the second `then()` statement) first when I don't want it to do that till after the DB data is saved. I'm not sure how to force the state change to happen after the DB data is saved.

Things I've tried:

1) Putting the state change directly after the the function code, within the first then(). This gives the error:

> Error getting documents:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: You need to return a promise from the first callback. If you don't, there's nothing to wait for.

Comment: In addition to the above, the reason you see the setState error is because youre using `function() {}` instead of an `() => {}`. Arrow functions maintain the 'this' context that they are declared in, `function() {}`s do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to wrap your set state and console log in another function. Without that you are passing two arguments to then, one is the result of console.log and the other is the result of this.setState. Those are synchronous calls the way you have written it.